# ¿Como creo un botón en Java para consultar los registros de una tabla de MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Quisiera crear un método en la clase `Conexion` para consultar los registros de una tabla de MySQL, de tal forma que se puede ingresar el número de cédula de la persona y luego, al presionar el botón, buscar y que aparezcan los demás datos de esta persona, los cuales ya están guardados en la tabla `estudiante`.

Hasta el momento el programa ya me permite insertar registros, solo me faltaría esa parte de buscarlos.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier colaboración.

[image: GUI]

Clase Conexión

```
package datos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import modelo.Estudiante;

public class Conexion {
    private PreparedStatement pstmt;

    public Conexion() {
    }

    private static Connection crearConexion(){
        Connection conexion = null;
        String usuario = "root";
        String password = "";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/anteproyectodb?user=" + usuario + "&password=" + password;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            if (conexion != null){
                System.out.println("Conectado a la base de datos.");
            }
        } catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("Error -> " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return conexion;
    }

    public boolean insertarEstudiante(Estudiante estudiante) {
        Connection conexion = crearConexion();

        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO estudiante VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

            pstmt = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, estudiante.getCedula());
            pstmt.setString(2, estudiante.getNombres());
            pstmt.setString(3, estudiante.getApellidos());
            pstmt.setInt(4, estudiante.getSemestre());

            return pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error -> " + e.getMessage());

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fijate si te sirve lo hice rapido modificando el codigo que tenes,creería que tiene que funcionar,como parametro paso un string podrías pasar el estudiante y usar el getCedula en el where.

```
public Estudiante buscarEstudiante(String numCedula) {
    Estudiante e = new Estudiante();
    Connection conexion = crearConexion();
    Statement stat = null;

    try {
        stat = conexion.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " estudiante " WHERE Cedula = '" + numCedula + "'";
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            e.setCedula((rs.getString("Cedula")));
            e.setNombres((rs.getString("Nombres")));
            e.setApellidos((rs.getString("Apellidos")));
            e.setSemestre((rs.getInt("Semestre")));
        }
    } catch (Exception e {
        System.err.println("Error -> " + e.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
      return e;
}
```